# Somar Tráfego Zabbix Aggregate SNMP

Tags: zabbix

Estou precisando somar tráfego de interfaces de um roteador via snmp. veja abaixo como estou fazendo:

1 Opção configurado:

```
Type : calculated
Key : anything.something
Formula : last("ifInOctets.2")+last("ifInOctets.8")
Type of information : numéric (float)
Units : B or bps
Store and show values : as is
```

2 Opção Configurado

```
Name: Total traffic on $1
Type: Calculated
Key: total.traffic.[{#SNMPVALUE}]
Formula: last("ifInOctets.3[{#SNMPVALUE}]")+last("ifInOctets.13[{#SNMPVALUE}]")
Type of information: Numeric(unsigned)
Data type: Decimal
Units: bps
```

Nenhuma das opções acima consegui somar o tráfego da `interface ifInOctets.3` e `ifInOctets.13`

Alguém pode me dar uma dica?

Answer (score 0):

Caros amigos eu fiz da forma abaixo e também nao funcionou.

grpsum["BGPFIREWALLMASTER",("ifInOctets.3")+sum("ifInOctets.13"),max,5]

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite!

Vamos lá, eu montei o meu exatamente neste formato.

```
last("db.odbc.select[tickets.open,whmcs]")+last("db.odbc.select[tickets.open,whmcs]")
```

A documentação tem bastante exemplo, é uma boa idéia seguir.
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated

Dúvidas, continue comentando.

Abraço.

Answer (score -1):

Trocar o "type of information" para "numeric(float)"